# I can't add any pokemon to gyms even when a slot is open

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

I went to one of my Teams gyms and there were a few slots still open so I clicked on add and I backed out real quick because I wanted to level up my Pokémon a little more. When i did i went to go put it back in but the button had disappeared but there were still two slots open. So I went to another one of my Teams gyms but just like the last gym there were slots open but the add button was no longer there. I understand the whole leveling up thing. But I should be able to add my Pokémon if there are still slots open just like how I was gonna do before I decided to level him up first. I tried restarting the game and my phone in hopes that was the issue but it wasn't. So now none of the gyms that my Team has I can put any Pokémon in even when there's slots open to put them in there which is kinda making me upset considering thats 1/3 of the game...so if someone can explain to me why even though there are open slots why can't I make my Pokémon join them anymore and what can I do to fix the issue? Like I said I was able to join them earlier until I backed out real quick to level my Pokémon CP up a few more digits. Go to go back in not even a minute later and now no gym for my Team will let me join them. Join button is completely gone now.

Comment: How are you working out "open slots" for the gym? Please refer to this  answer http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/273438/140518 for some info about gym levels and Pokemon spaces available.

Comment: It might help if you can post a screenshot? It sounds like those slots have been taken by the time you come back.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me a few days ago. I was with 4 friends and only one space in the gym (we're all in the same team) and only one of us could put a pokemon in the gym. 
It turned out to be, that the game I think has a bug that only enables the first person who entered the gym to add pokemon and so on.

Comment: In fact, it's probably a feature. It lock the gym to prevent other players too add pokemon in the slot while you are adding one.

Comment: Yeah, it could be that aswell. I think its a good think actually you dont lose your spot to other players.

Answer (score -3):

A gym, when totally defeated, never loses its initial level. If you and a team of 3 took down a level 2 gym, then only 2 Pokémon could go into that gym until you guys level it more. Similarly, if you and 2 friends took down a level 5 gym, you could put three Pokémon on it. Though the gym only shows one empty spot, it actually has 2 more open until other team members fill it or a rival team takes it down.

Edit: Source: Personal experience.

Comment: This is confusing, but if I understand what you're saying, it's incorrect. When a team completely takes down a rival gym, it starts with no team. The 1st person to take it by adding a Pokemon immediately levels it up to level 2, because adding a Pokemon to a gym adds 2,000 prestige, which is the threshold for level 2. This opens another spot for their team. The next threshold is 4,000, which means the next Pokemon that is added takes it up to level 3, opening another slot. After that slot is filled, the prestige will be on 6,000, requiring some training to level it again (level 4 is 8k).

Comment: @TimMalone Yeah, that's what I said. Except you added more figures. Bravo-yay, I bet you're so proud of yourself.

Comment: And it's not confusing, you actually just made my answer more convoluted.

Comment: Actually, Tim's answer is way more clear than yours is.  The way you described it sounds like the gym level carries over at the point it was when you defeated it, which is wrong.

Comment: @Frank it actually does, you just have to place in enough Pokémon to accommodate it.

Comment: I don't think that's correct at all.  What proof do you have of that?

Comment: @Frank Happy now?

Comment: Nope.  I think you're wrong, and you have nothing to back it up.  Therefore, the downvote stays.  My personal experience differs from yours, and without anything more to back it up, I think you're misunderstanding the gym mechanics.

Comment: The way you waved off Tim Malone's comment as being "exactly like yours" but "more convoluted" makes me think that you didn't understand it, because it is almost strictly contradictory to yours. His position, [shared by others,](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/282995/161656) is that gym level is strictly based on prestige, and that the prestige you incidentally gain from adding new Pokemon is enough to [take it immediately to level three](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/275812/161656), but not higher. Please explain the precise point on which your experience differs.

Comment: @Eikre My experience differs on account of the times that my father and I took down a level 2 gym and there wasn't another spot open, plus the time that we took a level 4 down with 2 other people, then had 4 spots open. I know what I'm saying. Stop downvoting.

Comment: Those are perceptions, but they are not accountable to an alternate theory. In your recollection, did the level 2 gyms not gain 2,000 prestige each time you placed a Pokemon, or did it successfully get up to 4,000 prestige but not move to level 3? Did the level 4 gym start out with more prestige than usual, or was it like the level 2 gym and gave you a number other than 2000 prestige per placed Pokemon, or gain levels based on a different prestige-to-level schedule?

Comment: @Eikre He's not asking about prestige, he's asking about placing 'Mon in a gym. You people are so obsessed with unnecessary details. I've answered his question sufficiently, haven't I? Or do you just want to crap on me more?

Comment: Your answer is under significant factual dispute, which means that it is insufficient. The details are not unnecessary because they are contradictory to your answer and you have not offered refutation beyond stating that you `know what you're saying`, which is something I'm certain the rest of us also think about ourselves. If you have discovered a heretofore unknown behavior in the game, it would be very beneficial for other players if you documented it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45680/discussion-between-eikre-and-tothemax).